# Atom cannot be launched after running it the first time as root

Tags: atom-editor, root

On Ubuntu, I installed Atom from the .deb package. But I mistakenly run it as root on the first time.

Then I get this error:

```
$ atom
$ /usr/bin/atom: line 185: /home/fabien/.atom/nohup.out: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3):

A `~/.atom` directory has been created with the root privileges.

It can be solved:

- by changing the `~/.atom` owner:

  ```
  sudo chown -R -v <username> ~/.atom
  ```
- by simply removing this directory:

  ```
  sudo rm -fr ~/.atom
  ```